# How do I create writable readonly rootfs using yocto?

Tags: overlay, yocto, readonly, rootfs

I want to create writable rootfs using Yocto. I tried with meta-readonly-rootfs-overlay layer and just included it into stm32mp135f yocto build process but seems like it is not making a writable readonly rootfs.

I tried with meta-readonly-rootfs-overlay layer with mickeldore branch and just included it into stm32mp135f yocto build process but seems like it is not making a writable readonly rootfs.

Comment: how can it be writeable and readonly at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an [Image Features](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/4.0.15/ref-manual/features.html?highlight=image%20feature#image-features), the one you are looking for is `read-only-rootfs`.

A complete guide is in the docs: [Creating the Root Filesystem](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/4.0.15/dev-manual/read-only-rootfs.html#creating-a-read-only-root-filesystem).

You need to set either `IMAGE_FEATURES` or `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES` with the added feature.

- `IMAGE_FEATURES` if you set it in your image recipe (`IMAGE_FEATURES += "read-only-rootfs"`)
- `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES` if you set it in the `local.conf` (`EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "read-only-rootfs"`

---

I missed a part of the question, on the overlay.

You can use the overlay class provided by Yocto: [overlayfs.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/meta/classes-recipe/overlayfs.bbclass). It provides a way to setup an external partition as an overlay, making it writable for your scripts/binaries/configuration. You can also use [overlayfs-etc.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/plain/meta/classes-recipe/overlayfs-etc.bbclass) if you only want to overlay `/etc`.

Comment: Yes I tried that and its creating rootfs totally readonly but I need to create a writable rootfs like a overlay filesystem does so that symlinked file/scripts could work.

Comment: @stack-shailu I have updated my answer with details on the overlay part.